# dplyr to calculate of prevalence of a variable in a condition

Tags: r, dplyr

I am new in the dplyr world - so sorry if the question might sound simple,
basically, I am interested in calculating the number of entries that are larger than 0.5 for each column. If they are lower than 0.5 I consider them as zero. I don't mind having a vector, that stores this number.

here is the example

```
messy <- data.frame(samples = c("s1", "s2", "s3", "s4"),
                    o1 = c(0.5, 0.7, 0.8, 0.6),
                    o2 = c(0.2, 0.8, 0.8, 0.1),
                    o3 = c(0.9, 0.2, 0.0, 0.1),
                    o4 = c(0.1, 0.6, 0.4, 0.4))
bb <- gather(messy, otu, counts, o1:o4)

bb %>% filter(counts > 0.5) %>% group_by(otu) %>% summarize(fre=n())
bb$fre/4
```

** update,
I believe the code in the example is what I wanted to have.

Comment: `tidydata %>% dplyr::count(value > 0.5)`?

Comment: for each column, I meant. In this example, at the end, I would have four values.

Comment: `tidydata %>% dplyr::count(key, value > 0.5)`? If you don't like that format, you might use `tidyr::spread` next or something similar.

Comment: using spread, gives "Error: Please supply column name"; the one you recommend, returns two column, one logical, the other integer.

Comment: @Frank - I fixed the matrix to make the result reproduced; also not sure, if my "gather" was correctly formulated. Thanks

Comment: I think, i got the answer on my own - so not sure, If I should remove the question or not, considering 2 people have down voted the question until now.

Answer (score 1):

You can do `colSums(messy > 0.5)`. 
This doesn't use **dplyr** but it is very simple and efficient.

Comment: the question is only related to the dplyr