# rolling count of var1 or var2 by group in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to do a rolling count for variable one or two if they have group x.

Essentially I want something get back `new_var1` and `new_var2` in this example, where every time `Var1` **or** `Var2` has the combination `a` and group `f` it counts, or `b` and group `f` and so on. So, the overall appearances of `a` in each group are counted, regardless if `a` appears in column `Var1` or `Var2`. However, the counts must be assigned to the proper colum. So, if `a` appears in column `Var1` then the actual count must be assigned to column `new_var1`. Accordingly, for `a` in `Var2` the actual count is to be in `new_var2`.

```
x <- expand.grid(letters[1:5],letters[1:5],KEEP.OUT.ATTRS = FALSE)
x <- x[x[,1]!=x[,2],c(2,1)]
x <- data.frame(x,group=as.character(rep(letters[c(1,2,1,4,1)+5],each=4)))
x<- data.frame(x,new_var1 = c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,3,4,5,6))
x<- data.frame(x,new_var2 = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,5,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,6,3,6,3))`



  Var2 Var1 group new_var2 new_var1
    a    b     f        1        1
    a    c     f        2        1
    a    d     f        3        1
    a    e     f        4        1
    b    a     g        1        1
    b    c     g        2        1
    b    d     g        3        1
    b    e     g        4        1
    c    a     f        2        5
    c    b     f        3        2
    c    d     f        4        2
    c    e     f        5        2
    d    a     i        1        1
    d    b     i        2        1
    d    c     i        3        1
    d    e     i        4        1
    e    a     f        3        6
    e    b     f        4        3
    e    c     f        5        6
    e    d     f        6        3
```

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

I managed to get this working:

```
x <- data.table(x)
x[, new_var1a := seq(.N) , by = c('Var1','group')]
x[, new_var2a := seq(.N) , by = c('Var2','group')]

   Var2 Var1 group new_var2 new_var1 new_var1a new_var2a
 1:    a    b     f        1        1         1         1
 2:    a    c     f        2        1         1         2
 3:    a    d     f        3        1         1         3
 4:    a    e     f        4        1         1         4
 5:    b    a     g        1        1         1         1
 6:    b    c     g        2        1         1         2
 7:    b    d     g        3        1         1         3
 8:    b    e     g        4        1         1         4
 9:    c    a     f        2        5         1         1
10:    c    b     f        3        2         2         2
11:    c    d     f        4        2         2         3
12:    c    e     f        5        2         2         4
13:    d    a     i        1        1         1         1
14:    d    b     i        2        1         1         2
15:    d    c     i        3        1         1         3
16:    d    e     i        4        1         1         4
17:    e    a     f        3        6         2         1
18:    e    b     f        4        3         3         2
19:    e    c     f        5        6         2         3
20:    e    d     f        6        3         3         4
```

But it treats var1 and var2 independently. Which I do not want.

Comment: Its is unclear what you are asking to me. Wy does this line ` c    a     f        2        5` have the 2 and the 5?

Comment: Sorry - I'm getting a bit confused about this myself. Essentially, at line `c a f 2 5` - this is is the 2nd time `c` has matched group `f` and the 5th time `a` has matched `f` - I guess it's a rolling frequency of 'group' with respect to `Var1` and `Var2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, your problem is more an algorithm problem so we'll use a loop instead of **dplyr** or **data.table**. FOR ME, using loops in R opten means using Rcpp. So this is my answer:

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(BH)]]
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
using namespace Rcpp;

// the C-style upper-case macro name is a bit ugly
#define foreach BOOST_FOREACH

// [[Rcpp::export]]
ListOf<IntegerVector> new_vars(const IntegerVector& Var1,
                               const IntegerVector& Var2,
                               int n_Var,
                               ListOf<IntegerVector> ind_groups) {

  int nrow = Var1.size();
  IntegerVector new_var1a(nrow, NA_INTEGER); 
  IntegerVector new_var2a(nrow, NA_INTEGER); 

  for (int i = 0; i < ind_groups.size(); i++) {
    IntegerVector counts(n_Var);
    foreach(const int& j, ind_groups[i]) {
      new_var1a[j] = ++counts[Var1[j]];
      new_var2a[j] = ++counts[Var2[j]];
    }
  }

  return List::create(Named("new_var1a") = new_var1a, 
                      Named("new_var2a") = new_var2a);
}


/*** R
x <- expand.grid(letters[1:5],letters[1:5],
                 KEEP.OUT.ATTRS = FALSE, 
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
x <- x[x[,1]!=x[,2],c(2,1)]
x <- data.frame(x,group=as.character(rep(letters[c(1,2,1,4,1)+5],each=4)))
x <- data.frame(x,new_var1 = c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,3,4,5,6))
x <- data.frame(x,new_var2 = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,5,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,6,3,6,3))


getNewVars <- function(x) {

  Vars.levels <- unique(c(x$Var2, x$Var1))

  new_vars <- new_vars(
      Var1 = match(x$Var1, Vars.levels) - 1,
      Var2 = match(x$Var2, Vars.levels) - 1,
      n_Var = length(Vars.levels), 
      ind_groups = split(seq_along(x$group) - 1, x$group)
  )

  cbind(x, new_vars)
}

getNewVars(x)
*/
```

Put this in a ".cpp" file and source it.

PS: Make sure to use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`.

Comment: why *"instead of dplyr"*? the question is not tagged with [tag:dplyr] and actually OP is using [tag:data.table]. *"using loops in R means using Rcpp"* well, no, it does not mean that.

Comment: @Cath You're completely right! Sorry, I was traumatize by another question with **dplyr** (https://stackoverflow.com/a/45244041/6103040). And the second sentence it's more a statement that is my point of view. I've updated my answer accordindly. Tell me if it's OK now.

Comment: well `dplyr` can be traumatizing... ;-)

Comment: This is awesome @F.Privé. Thanks.

Comment: @Skiptoniam If you are happy with the answer, please validate it.

Answer (score 1):

Solution with dplyr, by first casting the data from wide to long format, while keeping the row id to later merge again.

---

Sample data

```
df = read.table(text="  Var2 Var1 group new_var2 new_var1
    a    b     f        1        1
    a    c     f        2        1
    a    d     f        3        1
    a    e     f        4        1
    b    a     g        1        1
    b    c     g        2        1
    b    d     g        3        1
    b    e     g        4        1
    c    a     f        2        5
    c    b     f        3        2
    c    d     f        4        2
    c    e     f        5        2
    d    a     i        1        1
    d    b     i        2        1
    d    c     i        3        1
    d    e     i        4        1
    e    a     f        3        6
    e    b     f        4        3
    e    c     f        5        6
    e    d     f        6        3",header=T)

df = df[,c("Var2","Var1","group")]
```

---

Code

```
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)
df$id = seq(1,nrow(df))
df2 = melt(df, id.vars=c("id", "group")) %>% arrange(id)
df2 = df2 %>% group_by(group,value) %>% mutate(n= row_number())

df = df %>% left_join(df2[df2$variable=="Var1",c("id","n")], by="id") 
df = df %>% left_join(df2[df2$variable=="Var2",c("id","n")], by="id")
colnames(df)[colnames(df)=="n.x"]="new_var1"
colnames(df)[colnames(df)=="n.y"]="new_var2"
```

Optionally add `df2 = df2 %>% group_by(group,value,id) %>% mutate(n=max(n))` if a line can contain the same variables (which is not the case in your example).

Output

```
   Var2 Var1 group id new_var1 new_var2
1     a    b     f  1        1        1
2     a    c     f  2        1        2
3     a    d     f  3        1        3
4     a    e     f  4        1        4
5     b    a     g  5        1        1
6     b    c     g  6        1        2
7     b    d     g  7        1        3
8     b    e     g  8        1        4
9     c    a     f  9        5        2
10    c    b     f 10        2        3
11    c    d     f 11        2        4
12    c    e     f 12        2        5
13    d    a     i 13        1        1
14    d    b     i 14        1        2
15    d    c     i 15        1        3
16    d    e     i 16        1        4
17    e    a     f 17        6        3
18    e    b     f 18        3        4
19    e    c     f 19        6        5
20    e    d     f 20        3        6
```

---

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @Florian. This is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

The `dcast()` function from the `data.table` package allows us to  [reshape multiple value variables simultaneously](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-reshape.html). This can be used to avoid the double left join in [Florian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45278081/3817004):

```
library(data.table)
long <- melt(setDT(x)[, rn := .I], id.vars = c("rn", "group"), 
             measure.vars = c("Var1", "Var2"), value.name = "Var")[
               , variable := rleid(variable)][
                 order(rn), new_var := rowid(group, Var)][]
dcast(long, rn + group ~ ..., value.var = c("Var", "new_var"))[, rn := NULL][]
```

> ```
>     group Var_1 Var_2 new_var_1 new_var_2
>  1:     f     b     a         1         1
>  2:     f     c     a         1         2
>  3:     f     d     a         1         3
>  4:     f     e     a         1         4
>  5:     g     a     b         1         1
>  6:     g     c     b         1         2
>  7:     g     d     b         1         3
>  8:     g     e     b         1         4
>  9:     f     a     c         5         2
> 10:     f     b     c         2         3
> 11:     f     d     c         2         4
> 12:     f     e     c         2         5
> 13:     i     a     d         1         1
> 14:     i     b     d         1         2
> 15:     i     c     d         1         3
> 16:     i     e     d         1         4
> 17:     f     a     e         6         3
> 18:     f     b     e         3         4
> 19:     f     c     e         6         5
> 20:     f     d     e         3         6
> ```

#### Explanation

`setDT(x)` coerces `x` to `data.table`, then a column with row numbers is added before reshaping from wide to long format. Just to get nicer looking column names from the subsequent `dcast()`, the variables are renamed (for this `[, variable := sub("Var", "", variable)]` can be used as alternative to `[, variable := rleid(variable)]`).

The important step is the numbering of appearances of each `Var` within each `group` using `rowid()` grouped by `group` and `Var`.

Now, the result has two value columns. Finally, it is reshaped back from long to wide format again, and the `rn` column is removed as no longer needed.

#### Data

```
x <- expand.grid(letters[1:5], letters[1:5], KEEP.OUT.ATTRS = FALSE)
x <- x[x[, 1] != x[, 2], c(2, 1)]
x <- data.frame(
  x, 
  group = as.character(rep(letters[c(1, 2, 1, 4, 1) + 5], each = 4)),
  new_var1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 6),
  new_var2 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6, 3, 6, 3))
```